# Django : MixIn or One-to-One for User

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a Django project containing among others, 2 models : `Contact` and `User`.
I want a contact to have the ability to be transformed into a user.

I am hesitating between 2 choices :

- Using MixIn to make my `User` inherit from `Contact`
- Using One-to-One but in the reverse way from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Here is option 1:

```
#models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class OwningCompany(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Entreprise(models.Model):
    owning_company = models.ForeignKey(OwningCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Contact(models.Model):
    owning_company = models.ForeignKey(OwningCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)

class User(Contact, AbstracUser):
    pass
```

And here is option 2 :

```
#models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class OwningCompany(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Entreprise(models.Model):
    owning_company = models.ForeignKey(OwningCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Contact(models.Model):
    owning_company = models.ForeignKey(OwningCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)

class User(AbstractUser):
    contact = models.OneToOneField(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Might be of interest to know that I will always query for a single `OwningCompany`.

What is the best way of doing this ?